# TOleContainer does not load Excel on Windows 10, but it works on Windows XP - is the end-of-support for TOleContainer in Delphi?

Tags: excel, delphi, windows-10, windows-xp, ole

I am using Delphi TOleContainer components with the variable name SContainer and I am loading the Excel file into it using the code:

```
function CreateTExcelApp(aOwner: TComponent; AVisible:Boolean=True): TExcelApplication;
var
   Res: TExcelApplication;
begin
   Res:=TExcelApplication.Create(aOwner);

   if Res = nil then
     raise Exception.Create(rsNoExcelInstalled);

   Res.ConnectKind:=ckNewInstance;
   Res.Connect;

   if AVisible then begin
     if Res.WindowState[LCID] = TOLEEnum(xlMinimized) then
        Res.WindowState[LCID] := TOLEEnum(xlNormal);
     Res.ScreenUpdating[LCID] := true;
   end;

   Res.Visible[LCID] := AVisible;

   Result:=Res;
end;

procedure SDM.CreateExcelApplication;
begin
  try
  if not Assigned(FExcel)then
  begin
    FExcel := CreateTExcelApp(self,False);
  end;

  FExcel.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,
  EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,
  EmptyParam,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,0);
  FillExcelWithData;
  FExcel.OnSheetChange:=OnExcelSheetChanged;
  FExcelChanged:=false;
  finally
    FExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save(0);
    FExcel.Workbooks.Close(0);
    FExcel.Quit;
  end;
end;

var SContainer: TOleContainer;

SDM.CreateExcelApplication;
SContainer.CreteObjectFromFile(ExcelFilePath)
```

This code works (whole Excel container and file within it is loaded in the Delphi application instance) on Windows XP and has always worked on later Windows versions. But Windows 10 opens Excel file in the separate Excel instance (instead loading all the Excel container in the TOleContainer component in the Delphi application) and then Windows 10 loads some parts of the Excel file in the TOleContainer but no Excel menus, ribbon and toolbars are loaded in the TOleContainer. That is different from the behavior on Windows XP machine, in which Windows XP loads entire Excel application in the TOleContainer with all the menus, ribbon and toolbars.

Are the some incompatibilies between OLE technologies, Excel and Windows 10?

I am using Delphi 6, but I guess that problem can be for later Delphi editions as well.

**The question made more accurate:** The fact, that Windows 10 does not load menus/ribbon/toolbars is not so bad, the worst thing is that Windows 10 loads the visual preview of the first sheet only and no other sheets are loaded by Windows 10. That means that any futher programmatical access of the cells from other sheets gives OLE error and other error message. So, menus/ribbon/toolbars can stay unloaded, but sheets should be present.

`Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings... - Macro Settings - Macro Settings - Enable all macros (not recommened; potentially dangerous code can run)` select prevents the load of additional instance of Excel application and no warning about macros is displayed, the sheet is immediately loaded in the container, but this settings does not solve the problem, that only first sheet (or its visual preview) is loaded in the TOleContainer and no other sheets are loaded.

Comment: You nowhere mention the Office/Excel versions - are those exactly the same on both Windows installations? Have you had your hands on different Excel versions and verified that several combinations of that on the OS (i.e. [Office XP on Win10 and Office 2010 on WinXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_Office)) are not the culprit, but instead the OS versions themselves?

Comment: It is not so easy to quickly see the Excel version - MS hides 'About' box. But XP has Excel 2007, and Windows 10 has Microsoft Office Professiona Plus 2016. So, of course, there are Excel differences.

Comment: @TomR Well, there are HUGE differences between those versions. Switch from MDI to SDI (again), Ribbons. A lot has changed. I made a small example to see what you meant exactly. For me (O2019) the preview is also loaded separately. First the file is loaded in the container. The the file is loaded in a separate Window and the one in the container gets cross-out lines in it. But I can activate the container by double clicking in it. The preview disapears then. Well... not exactly.. it hides behind your own window (I can see a little of the previous Excel window :) (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Also the container gives the ribon (lots of space) and expands over my entire window. Not just the space I reserved for the TOleContainer. It's clear Excel doesn't want to be in a TOleContainer :)

Comment: BTW. Does this work better for you? `OleContainer1.CreateObjectFromFile('C:\Temp\Test.xlsx', false);
OleContainer1.AutoActivate := aaGetFocus;
OleContainer1.DoVerb(ovPrimary); // <-- !!` (So doing the DoVerb(ovPrimary);)

Comment: Thank you @Rik I will check the code but your suggestion (in a bit modified form) has already solved my issue: you suggested activating the container with double click, it didn't work for me, but I had 'Edit' and 'Open' commands on mouse-right-button popup menu and 'Open' opened the Excel that was loaded in the container, in the separate window and my program could access its sheets and cells indeed. So, Excel visually is not in the container, but otherwise it can be manipulated from the program and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @TomR Yes. I investigated containers a long time ago and found they had too much issues with Office. Even the DoVerb(ovPrimary); will produce problems if there are other instances of Excel open outside your program. Now I just use CreateOleObject('Excel.Application') (late binding) to automate Excel. Much better and stable. If you don't need a visual OleContainer I would recommend switching to CreateOleObject('Excel.Application') and late binding (you still have access to the entire Excel-instance).